# Possessive form of "you guys"

Tags: grammar

The term "you guys" is so widely used, I'm surprised it doesn't have a possessive. I hear "Your guys'es" all the time but surely that's not correct. What should be used for the possessive of a group of people.

Comment: *"What should be used for the possessive of a group of people?"* In the U.S. South, it should be *y'all's*. Elsewhere, it should simply be *your*.

Comment: "youse guys'" .

Comment: What I hear is “you guys’s” (not “your guys’s”). And correctness is a non-issue in contexts/registers that admit of anything so slangy as “you guys” in the first place.

Comment: *The guy's trousers are on fire* - one guy. *The guys' trousers are on fire* - more than one guy. Therefore *You guys' trousers are on fire*. seems straightforward to me.

Comment: @GregLee -- No, it's "youse guyses".

Comment: @HotLicks, yes, "youse guyses" was the answer given by Tom Auger the previous time this question came up.  That sounds okay to me, too, but I'd spell it "guys's".  The "youse" doesn't make any sense to me, grammatically, but it is still my native speaker's intuition that that "youse guys'/guys's" is the right form.

Answer (score 0):

Any possessive form of this slang would be awkward at best. It's better to rephrase the statement; for example, **"I hear that this car belongs to you guys."**

Comment: Mark Hubbard Why do you consider "you guys" to be slang?

Comment: This is appropriate usage and a clean solution to the issue. However, it doesn't answer the OP question ("What should be used for the possessive of a group of people?") unless you are saying that there is no such valid possessive form.